# How to receive data that has an variable number of classes with retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am building an android application and I am having the following problem:

Using Retrofit2, so far I've been sending HTTP requests by creating a response and request class. Now I need to make a request that will return the data has unspecified variable number of classes. How to create a response class when I don't know how much data will be sent and how to pack that data into app textview when I don't know how much textview can be?

```
"data": {

    "mData": [
        {
            "Field1": 262,
            "Field2": 6695,
        },
        {
            "Field1": 252,
            "Field2": 3295,
        }
             ]
},
"errors": false}
```

Comment: Views can be dynamically created based on response. About response, if you can share a sample response that you have built or expecting to build.

Comment: How can I do this dynamically? I will put this into first post

Comment: By looking at your sample response, it looks like mData would be having array of 'n' of json objects but those objects are having similar set of keys like Field1 and Field2

Comment: Yes, they are similar, so I can just use mData like array list?

Comment: then I don't think so your json response is dynamic with unspecified variables (keys), because I said response with keys of json objects and json arrays are defined.

Comment: Ok, but how can I make textview for this array members?

Comment: Adding dynamic array of TextView in a layout will cause memory consumption. Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I shared details in the comment and as you confirmed the sample response, you are actually not getting a response with "unspecified variable number of classes" but the response is actually having same set of keys for JSON arrays and JSON objects. For example, "data", "mData", "Field1", "Field2", etc.

Now to answer your question about how you would, you just need to get the "mData" JSON array and iterate through each JSON object.

About adding views dynamically, there are wrapper classes available for each view, for example, TextView, Button, etc. To create and add views dynamically, you can create and objects like:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view;

for (int i = 1; i < jsonObjctsCount; i++){
    // Add the text layout to the parent layout
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parentLayout, false);

    // In order to get the view we have to use the new view with text_layout in it
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText("Row " + i);

    // Add the text view to the parent layout
    parentLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: How to count json objects?

Comment: @Niklaus looks like you are new to android programming.

Comment: Yes, I am new in android

Comment: @Niklaus You basically need to parse the json response, I would suggest you to search on Google with "Android json parsing"

Comment: No problem, happy to help if you come across any issues in solving this puzzle!